# how to assign value to dropdownlist using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 2 Dropdownlist (ddlState, ddlPlace)based on the id selected by the state (ddlplace with be loaded). I have a record to be displayed in the corresponding fields,
ddlState is assigned properly and then BindPlaceByStateId is a function to fill values in ddlplace

```
$("#<%=txtId.ClientID%>").val(obj.Id);
$("#<%=txtCode.ClientID%>").val(obj.Code);
$("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>").val(obj.Name);
$("#<%=ddlState.ClientID%>").val(obj.State.Id);
// To Bind the Places By State Id
BindPlaceByStateId();
//alert(obj.Place.Id);
$("#<%=ddlPlace.ClientID%>").valueOf(obj.Place.Id);
```

Using that alert ddlPlace is getting filled properly. 
If i remove that alert(right now it is commented) ddlPlace is not assigned.

I need to assign the (obj.Place.Id) in ddlPlace

THANKS in advance

Comment: what code does `BindPlaceByStateId()` contain? Please share that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `document.ready()` function because it ensure all DOM element are properly loaded.
See example as follow:

```
        $("#<%=txtId.ClientID%>").val(obj.Id);
        $("#<%=txtCode.ClientID%>").val(obj.Code);
        $("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>").val(obj.Name);
        $("#<%=ddlState.ClientID%>").val(obj.State.Id);
        // To Bind the Places By State Id
        BindPlaceByStateId();
        //alert(obj.Place.Id);
        $(document).ready(function () {
           setTimeout(function(){  $("#<%=ddlPlace.ClientID%>").val(obj.Place.Id); }, 1000);
        });
```

Comment: Same again... Thanks. the ddplace is getting loaded and the exact value is not getting selected , when a alert is placed in between (exact value is assigned in ddlPlace)

Comment: ohh no .. same again : should i need to change my browser( i couldnt find were the bug is hidden)

Comment: you need to increase the time out to 2000 or 3000

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#ddlPlace").each(function() {
  if($(this).text() == 'Your Text') {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
  }                        
});
```

Comment: ohh no.. Same issue. Thanks ( as usual if alert is presented ddlPlace is assigned)

Comment: @user3256201, please check if my edited answer works.

Comment: Same again.. Thanks. the ddplace is getting loaded and the exact value is not getting selected , when a alert is placed in between (exact value is assigned in ddlPlace)